# Updating audio source from json with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, audio, mobile

I have seen many ways to do this but im having a hard time implementing it within the code I want. Im modifying someone elses (open source) code and I guess im lost. I want to play a sound clip for each question in questionlist  and ask a question relevant to that file. I keep striking out so Instead of posting my awful code, I will post the clean javascript and ask for pointers. Ideally i would like it in the json and updated through the html but its not been working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var questionNumber=0;
    var questionBank=new Array();
    var stage="#game1";
    var stage2=new Object;
    var questionLock=false;
    var numberOfQuestions;
    var score=0;

    $.getJSON('activity.json', function(data) {
        for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){ 
            questionBank[i]=new Array;
            questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
            questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
            questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
            questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
        }
        numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length;       
        displayQuestion();
    })//gtjson

    function displayQuestion() {
        var rnd=Math.random()*3;
        rnd=Math.ceil(rnd);
        var q1;
        var q2;
        var q3;
        if(rnd==1 {
            q1=questionBank[questionNumber[1];
            q2=questionBank[questionNumber[2];
            q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3];
        }

        if(rnd==2) {
            q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1];
            q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2];
            q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];
        }

        if(rnd==3) {
            q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1];
            q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2];
            q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3];
        }

        $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">'+questionBank[questionNumber][0]+'</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div>');

        $('.option').click(function() {
            if(questionLock==false) {
                questionLock=true;  
                //correct answer
                if(this.id==rnd) {
                    $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1">CORRECT</div>');
                    score++;
                }
                //wrong answer  
                if(this.id!=rnd) {
                    $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">WRONG</div>');
                }
                setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},1000);
            }
        })
    }//display question

    function changeQuestion() {     
        questionNumber++;

        if(stage=="#game1") {
            stage2="#game1";
            stage="#game2";
        } else {
            stage2="#game2";
            stage="#game1";
        }
        if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions {
            displayQuestion();
        } else {
            displayFinalSlide();
        }

        $(stage2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {
            $(stage2).css('right','-800px');
            $(stage2).empty();
        });
        $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {
            questionLock=false;
        });
    }//change question

    function displayFinalSlide() {      
        $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'</div>');

    }//display final slide  
});//doc ready
```

Any pointers? Also, trying to format code for this site via mobile is infuriating. Yes, i indented four spaces, yes i switched to desktop so that i could actually see the code option on the toolbar and yes, it still looks terrible.

Comment: For reference `Ctrl-K` ( which still should be easy from a mobile keyboard ) is a simple way to indent. Your question title may be a little misleading or at least not consistent with the body. Are you acutally trying "upload a sound recording"? Or are you just trying to "Play a file for each list member"? If the latter, then "where are the files?". A bit of common sense would have separate URL's for the audio and just list the URL only. Let the normal browser functions handle retrieval and playback.

Comment: Ive added a play function to the html and I want it to play files stored offline. But I want each soundfile to be tied to each question. Associating the two together is where im having trouble.